Does special relativity also imply that speed of sound is constant for all observers irrespective of their relative motion?
I am reading lec15 The Special Theory of Relativity from the Feynman lectures.

Poincaré made the following statement of the principle of relativity: “According to the principle of relativity, the laws of physical phenomena must be the same for a fixed observer as for an observer who has a uniform motion of translation relative to him, so that we have not, nor can we possibly have, any means of discerning whether or not we are carried along in such a motion.”

From what I understood from the lecture overall is that the reason for the speed of light being constant is so that an observer is not able to discern whether or not he is moving in a uniform motion. Wouldn't this also apply to the speed of sound or even the speed of a bullet which is known? because if they are not constant for an observer they will be able to discern if they are moving right? Is there anything special about light? wouldn't the theory apply to all things?

Speed measurements are quite complicated to perform, because it involves an indirect ratio of distance / time... Choosing a more direct, easily testable postulate may clear up much of the nonintuitive aura of SR.

The speed of sound is not constant for all observers, but this does not contradict the fact that the laws of physics are the same in all reference frames or imply that you can detect your absolute speed.
Lets imagine you have a long rod made of a particular material for which the speed of sound is $0.1c$ relative to the material of the rod. Let's also say another observer (Ben) has an identical rod in their rocket and is moving at $0.5c$ relative you. If Ben measures' the speed of sound in the rod that is at rest in his rocket he will also measure the speed of sound in the rod to be $0.1c$. So far the speed of sound appears to be constant, but when you measure the front of the sound wave in Ben's rod relative to your own reference frame the speed of the sound wave is given by the relativistic velocity addition formula : $$v_s = \frac{v +u'}{1+vu'}\ = \  \frac{0.5 +0.1}{1+0.5\times 0.1} \approx 0.57142,$$
where $u'$ is the sound velocity measured by Ben in his rod at rest in his rocket and $v$ is the velocity of Ben's rocket relative to you. To you the sound is moving at slightly over half the speed of light relative to your own reference frame. Hence we cannot call the speed of sound constant because different observers measure the speed of sound to be different in different reference frames. If Ben had sent a light signal from the back of his rod to the front of his rod, he would have measured the speed of the light signal to be $c$ and you would also measure the speed of that light signal as moving at $c$ relative to your own reference frame, because unlike sound the speed of light is the same for all observers, no matter what the velocity of the source of the light is. You can prove this to yourself by entering $v' = 1$ in the velocity addition equation above.
The laws of physics are the same for both you and Ben. The 'law' for the speed of sound in a rod of that particular material is given by:
$$v_s = \frac{v + 0.1'}{1+v\times 0.1} ,$$
where $v$ is the velocity of the rod. This 'law' works in any reference frame for any velocity of the rod relative to the observer. To Ben the velocity of the speed of sound in the rod at rest in your reference frame also appears to be $0.57142c$ relative to his reference frame while to you it is only moving at $0.1c$.

Thanks for the detailed answer! Can you please also elaborate a bit on: what is so special about the speed of light, why must it be constant while the same doesn't apply to other phenomenon? Is it just a empirically known fact or there is some reasoning behind it?

The speed of light might be better described as the speed of causality or the maximum speed of interaction. Light itself can move at less than c in a medium such as glass or water and c seems the speed of light when there is no medium, C appears to be the speed limit of the universe for everything and in a way it regulates how fast events unfold.  I am not sure you can prove the speed of light in a vacuum must be c from first principles and that may be why Einstein simply made it a postulate in relativity, rather than a derived quantity.

c appears to be a universal constant like the G, the gravitational constant. I don't think anyone really knows why the universal constants take on the particular values we observe. If you look at the relativistic velocity addition equation you will see that anything that moves at c will have the property that its speed is the same for all observers. It does not have to be light. However it does appear to be a property of anything that does not have rest mass.

The statement is that the laws of physics are the same in both frames, not that a specific solution will be the same in all frames. The laws of physics are based on differential equations. To get an actual solution you need both the differential equation and also the initial or boundary conditions.
So for your example of the bullet, the law of physics would be the differential equation describing the acceleration of the bullet down the barrel. The initial conditions would be the initial position and velocity. Even if different frames agree on the laws, they will disagree on the boundary conditions. So applying the same law of physics to the different initial conditions would result in different final velocities in two different frames.
There can only be one invariant speed, and that is $c$. All other speeds will be different in different frames. The principle of relativity does not contradict that

What is so special about light speed, why does the light speed have to be constant in all frames, what would happen if it was not?

We don’t know why the speed of light is special. We just observe that it is and build our science according to how we observe that the world behaves. Here is a decent list of experiments that examine the various effects of this special speed https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/experiments.html

No.
The speed of light is more closely related to the structure of spacetime than anything else. Traveling along null curves, a photon moves at the highest speed it can while staying on “causal” paths, i.e. ones that don’t involve breaking causality with time travel or the like. This speed is that such that the spacetime interval, $\mathrm{d}s^2$, is zero. Since the spacetime interval is Lorentz-invariant, so is the observed speed of light.
This is more generally a property of massless objects that they follow null curves. The speed of gravity and of the strong force (i.e. the speed at which you see gluons move) are also Lorentz invariant. The apparent velocity of any massive object (bullets, molecules in a pressure wave, etc.) is not Lorentz invariant in general.
The speed of sound is the speed at which a pressure wave propagates through air, and is around a million times slower. Sound, unlike light, is just a bunch of molecules hitting each other in sequence, which happens at a finite speed related to air pressure/temperature/composition etc. Sound moves with respect to the air, with the air’s rest frame being privileged over all others.
Consider this: if sound’s speed is Lorentz invariant and all observers see it moving at the same speed despite velocity or position, then why do supersonic planes produce shockwaves? The pilot of the plane would see the sound (and pressure waves) moving right past them, wouldn’t they? Resolution: the plane is moving faster than sound in the comoving reference frame of the air, leading to shockwaves. Unless the wind is really bad, it’s reasonable to approximate the air to be at rest relative to the ground as well.

The speed of sound (speed of pressure waves) is fundamentally related to the fluid medium in which the pressure waves travel. The governing reference frame for sound wave analysis is the frame at rest with respect to the bulk fluid (or solid) medium.
In the late 1800s, physicists knew that the same wave equation mathematically governed electromagnetic waves, and believed there was an aether field in which EM waves traveled, that served as the governing reference frame for light. The breakthrough in Relativity was the discovery that there is no such medium, and that the equations governing EM waves are equally true for all inertial observers.  This required a reassessment of the principles of classical mechanics (Newton's Laws).

"the discovery that there is no such medium" - that is not true. Einstein did not "discover" the absence of such a medium, he devised a conceptual framework in which it was not necessary to assume the existence of the medium - instead, different assumptions were made. The question of whether there is such a medium or not, remains an open question in physics.

Einstein was led to his conclusion partially by the Michaelson experiment and others, which gave a null result for existence of the aether.

As I say, Einstein did not "conclude" that there was no medium. He simply made different assumptions, which led to a theory which neither explicitly required nor denied the existence of a classical wave medium. Einstein wrote explicitly that he did not deny its existence - there's no grounds to claim Einstein falsified the concept, or ever regarded it as falsified. In fact Einstein and Lorentz (a major proponent of aether) eventually concluded that there was no experiment that could determine which of their two differing approaches was the correct one.
